# Linear Regression: Won't adding irrelevant features still improve the prediction

Tags: regression, linear-regression, linear-models

Assume we are predicting weight based on height: this is simple linear regression. If we now add gender, this creates multiple linear regression and improves our model, and makes it more capable of generalizing.

However, if instead of adding gender, we add the weather in Toronto (something irrelevant), won't this still contribute positively or neutrally to the model?

Comment: By adding more feature you will always increase (or keep the same) performance. You need some metrics that also penalizes the number of features.

Comment: @Lelouch That's not true, adding variables can worsen model performance, because of... overfitting.

Comment: If you add a feature that has no impact on the target, linear regression training will give this feature a zero coefficient anyway so will ignore it in predictions. If a (false) linear relationship is detected between weather and height during training then it will add errors (although probably small errors) to your predictions.

Comment: So it will deem the feature useless. But adding that feature will never negatively impact R^2?

Comment: @user2974951 It's implicite that I am talking about improving performances on train set

Comment: I guess the way to reduce the usage of bad features is to use Adjusted R^2.

Comment: (Adjusted) R^2 as computed on the train set won't help you either.